# Convert list to json and write to file (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, uwp

I writing code for UWP app and I need to convert List to json and wwrite this json to file.

Here is My class file code:

```
  private List<RootObject> ordersList;

    public List<RootObject> OrdersList
    {
        get { return ordersList; }
        set { ordersList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    private RootObject ordersChange;

    public RootObject OrdersChange
    {
        get { return ordersChange;}
        set { ordersChange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public  InWorkViewModel()
    {
      CreatingFile();
      Inwork_down();

    }


    public async void  Inwork_down()
    {

        string url = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/inc/get_from_wc.php/?wc_orders=processing_orders";
        var json = await FetchAsync(url);
        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
        OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);

    }

    public async void CreatingFile()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("InWork.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }

    public async void WriteOrderToFile()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.OrdersChange);
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("InWork.txt");
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, json);

        string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
    }

    public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }
```

I put breakpoint to this row `set { ordersChange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }` and it hits when i tap element from first list.

I call writing to file in xaml.cs like this.

```
    private  void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = this.DataContext as InWorkViewModel;
        viewModel?.WriteOrderToFile();}`
```

and set breakpoint on this row in class `string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);` and my `text` is null.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Hm, maybe breakpoint hits earlier? Because I see json in breakpoint.

Comment: Yeah, you can run to the next line of the code `string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);` by pressing F10 to see if the value of text is null.